# Sinatra easily get current path

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am using Sinatra and in erb, every time I had to generate a link, I have to hardcode it like this:

```
<li><a href=<%="/admin/users?page=#{i}"%>><%=i%></a></li>
```

Is there an easier, more "scalable" way to get the string "/admin/users?page=" and do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Generating%20URLs) and make a [helper](http://rubysource.com/using-sinatra-helpers-to-clean-up-your-code/).

```
# Assuming you're building a modular sinatra app but its not required.
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module UserLinkHelper
    def user_url(id)
      url("/admin/users?page=" + id.to_s)
    end
  end

  helpers UserLinkHelper
end

# Assuming you're using haml in your view, once again not required
%a{:href => user_url(i)}
```

I didn't test this but this should encompass the idea you're looking for.